# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility - Test Cases failing

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We're trying to use the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility but are hitting an issue when trying to migrate the work items. The errors are relating to Tase Cases and in particular Test Step IDs.

> OH-TFS-Connector-0054: Test Step Id cannot be empty and It must be valid number. Please check the Mapping and add valid mapping for the Test Step Id.

We have looked at the flagged work items and they all include Shared Steps, could this be the cause of the error as we can see nothing else wrong?

Comment: Can you please send us your logs located at <installation-path>/logs at ovsmu@opshub.com

Comment: I have emailed the logs to you. Thanks