# Opshub migration failures

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm migrating a large amount of projects from a on premise tfs2010 to vso, nearly all of them was able to migrate without any problems, but a few are creating errors. I am using Opshub Integration Manager Framework-OVSMU-V1.2.0.000.

1.
OH-TFS-Connector-0054: Test Step Id cannot be empty and It must be a valid number. Please check the Mapping and add valid mapping for the Test Step Id.

The most common error. This error is also described in [opshub-visual-studio-online-migration-utility-test-cases-failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909252/opshub-visual-studio-online-migration-utility-test-cases-failing), but has yet to receive an accepted answer. As mentioned in this post the cause if the problem might be Shared Steps, so I tried removing one from a test case, and that made it pass in the migration utility. Unfortunately I need those test cases and it is not feasible for me to just delete them.

2.
OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getCollectionMetaData. Server Error : TF201063: Adding a Test Case link to work item 18374 would result in a circular relationship. To create this link, evaluate the existing links, and remove one of the other links in the cycle.

After inspecting the Work Items that causes the error and concluding that there is no links, and no clear circular reference, not even a Shared Step linking to work item 18374. Upon further inspection I noticed that work item 18374 doesn't even exist.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. OH-TFS-Connector-0054: Test Step Id cannot be empty and It must be a valid number. Please check the Mapping and add valid mapping for the Test Step Id.

This issue is addressed in latest release of OVSMU (1.3.0.000). You can download from 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2

2. OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getCollectionMetaData. Server Error : TF201063: Adding a Test Case link to work item 18374 would result in a circular relationship.

This issue is scheduled for next release which will be out shortly. Check Visual Studio Gallery for further updates.

Thanks.